# How to use dynamic tailwind classes with JS switch statement and pass them correctly in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, switch-statement, tailwind-css

I am a beginner to Vue JS and I'm trying to create a function for assigning corresponding colours to the order statuses. I would like to use switch-statement to achieve this, that would grab the value of order status and pass it to the getStatusColour function(), like this:

```js
const getStatusColour = (orderStatus) => {
    let statusColour = "";
    switch (orderStatus) {
        case "new": 
            statusColour = "bg-green-100 text-green-900";
            break;
        case "preparing": 
            statusColour =  "bg-yellow-400 text-yellow-900";
            break;
        case "ready":
            statusColour = "bg-blue-200 text-blue-800";
            break;
        case "delivered":
            statusColour = "bg-green-300 text-green-800";
            break;
        case "failed": 
            statusColour = "bg-red-400 text-red-900";
            break;
        default:
            statusColour = "bg-gray-100 text-gray-800"
    }
    return statusColour;
}
```

Then in the `Index.vue` file I  have `export default { getStatusColour }`, I guess that's should be a mistake here.

And then in the template I call it like this:

```html
<span :class="getStatusColour(order.status)">{{ order.status }}</span>
```

But I keep getting `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _ctx.getStatusColour is not a function` error. I'll appreciate any help here.

Comment: How do you import the function?

Comment: Yeah, tailwind, it's imported correctly and works well in other parts, so I assume the issue in calling this functions

Comment: Alright, once this one is solved, I'd show an alternative way of doing this with Tailwind. You will see if it suits your needs. :)

Comment: Glad that I helped you with your issue. I edited my answer with my way of doing things. Not sure if it may help anyhow or give some cool ideas for your own implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown in the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#using_named_exports

---

Here is the whole github codebase.

`utils/test.js`

```js
const getStatusColour = (orderStatus) => {
  let statusColour = ''
  switch (orderStatus) {
    case 'new':
      statusColour = 'bg-green-100 text-green-900'
      break
    case 'preparing':
      statusColour = 'bg-yellow-400 text-yellow-900'
      break
    case 'ready':
      statusColour = 'bg-blue-200 text-blue-800'
      break
    case 'delivered':
      statusColour = 'bg-green-300 text-green-800'
      break
    case 'failed':
      statusColour = 'bg-red-400 text-red-900'
      break
    default:
      statusColour = 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-800'
  }
  return statusColour
}

export { getStatusColour }
```

`App.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div :class="getStatusColour(order.status)">
      This div do have the correct: `bg-green-100 text-green-900` on it
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { getStatusColour } from './utils/test'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      order: {
        status: 'new',
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getStatusColour,
  },
}
</script>
```

Here is a github repo to show that your code is working great so far: https://github.com/kissu/so-compute-exported-function

---

#### How I do personally handle this kind of flow

`callToAction.vue`

```html
<button
  class="flex items-center w-auto p-4 text-center ..."
  :class="[
    callToAction.types[color][variant],
    { 'opacity-50 cursor-not-allowed shadow-none': disabled },
  ]"
>
  Nice flexible button
</button>

<script>
export default {
props: {
  color: {
    type: String,
    default: 'primary',
  },
  variant: {
    type: String,
    default: 'enabled',
  },
  disabled: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
},

data() {
  return {
    callToAction: {
      types: {
        primary: {
          enabled: 'disabled:bg-primary-500 hover:bg-primary-700 bg-primary-500 text-primary-500',
          outlined: 'hover:bg-primary-a12 text-primary-500',
          reversed: 'text-primary-500',
        },
        secondary: {
          enabled: 'disabled:bg-secondary-500 hover:bg-secondary-700 bg-secondary-500 text-secondary-500',
          outlined: 'hover:bg-secondary-a12 text-secondary-500',
          reversed: 'text-secondary-500',
        },
        tertiary: {
          enabled: 'disabled:bg-tertiary-500 hover:bg-tertiary-700 bg-tertiary-500 text-tertiary-500',
          outlined: 'hover:bg-tertiary-a12 text-tertiary-500',
          reversed: 'text-tertiary-500',
        },
        bluegray: {
          enabled: 'disabled:bg-bluegray-500 hover:bg-bluegray-700 bg-bluegray-500 text-bluegray-500',
          outlined: 'hover:bg-bluegray-a12 text-bluegray-500',
          reversed: 'text-bluegray-500',
        },
        error: {
          enabled: 'disabled:bg-error-500 hover:bg-error-700 bg-error-500 text-error-500',
          outlined: 'hover:bg-error-a12 text-error-500',
          reversed: 'text-error-500',
        },
      },
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Then, call it in other pages/components with something like:

```html
<call-to-action color="tertiary" variant="reversed"></call-to-action>
```

Or let the defaults do it's job with `color="primary"`, `variant="enabled"` and so on...

PS: adding [validators](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#props) to props could be nice, will be more friendly for the other developers working on the project, figuring out all the possible values that can be passed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of kissu should fix your problem, but I would recomend use computed properties.
This way you can write less code and also you can create a default state which handles it when the input of `color` or `variant` is invalid.

```
<button
  class="flex items-center w-auto p-4 text-center ..."
  :class="[
    class_type,
    { 'opacity-50 cursor-not-allowed shadow-none': disabled },
  ]"
>

<script>
export default {
props: {
  color: {
    type: String,
    default: 'primary',
  },
  variant: {
    type: String,
    default: 'enabled',
  },
  disabled: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
},
computed: {
  class_type: function(){
    switch(this.variant)
    case "enabled": 
      return `disabled:bg-${this.color}-500 hover:bg-${this.color}-700 bg-${this.color}-500 text-${this.color}-500`
    case "outlined":
      return `hover:bg-${this.color}-a12 text-${this.color}-500`
    case "reversed": 
      return `text-${this.color}-500`
    default: 
      console.error("you didn't put a proper variant to this component")
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: this is not recommended, use safelist instead to achieve the same

Comment: You indeed cannot interpolate tailwind classes. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names The computed may be an idea otherwise indeed.