# How do I conditionally add multiple classes to a <span> based on an element within an array using Vue.js and Tailwind?

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

I have, in my js file, an array that lists all of the national parks along with a visitation *status*.

```js
var parksList = new Vue({
  el: "#parks",
  data: {
    parks: [
      { name: "Acadia", state: "Maine", status: "Pending" },
      { name: "American Samoa", state: "American Samoa", status: "Pending" },
      { name: "Arches", state: "Utah", status: "Visited" },
      ...
```

Based on the text of the status ("Pending" vs "Visited") I would like to conditionally apply **two** tailwind classes to the following span.

```html
<span class="py-1 px-3 rounded-full text-xs">{{park.status}}</span>
```

- If *status* = "Pending" —> apply classes *bg-purple-200* and
  *text-purple-600*
- If *status* = "Visited" —> apply classes *bg-green-200* and *text-green-600*

Would this be accomplished using v-bind:class and Vue Array Syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

class can co-exist with `:class` directive so it will merge these 2 classes when rendered.
try this:

```html
<span 
  class="py-1 px-3 rounded-full text-xs" 
  :class="{ 'text-green-600 bg-green-200': park.status == 'Pending', 'bg-purple-200 text-purple-600': park.status == 'Visited'}"
>
  {{park.status}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

On the following link, you'll find 2 approaches to have something flexible and readable.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67382023/8816585

I found mine a bit more flexible if used in components.

My idea is to pass some classes depending of the actual state/props

```html
<button
  class="flex items-center w-auto p-4 text-center ..."
  :class="[
    callToAction.types[color][variant],
    { 'opacity-50 cursor-not-allowed shadow-none': disabled },
  ]"
>
```