# TailwindCSS Why is the first class more important than the latter?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

```html
<p class="mt-1 mt-2" ></p>
```

Why does the above show margin 4 px instead of margin 8 px
Because the last class should be more important.

I'm having a lot of trouble when writing an "if" in vuejs because if writing normally New classes are always appended to the end.

- NuxtJS 2.15.8
- TailwindCSS 3.0.23
- postcss 8.4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a matter of priority CSS-wise (like specificity) but with Tailwind you should be using only one class at a time, because they are defined in a single file.

So should rather use some conditional to achieve the end result you're looking for. Check the second part of my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67382023/8816585). It's based on the answer of one of Tailwind's maintainer (in Github discussions).

This is the general idea

```html
<button
  class="flex items-center w-auto p-4 text-center ..."
  :class="[
    callToAction.types[color][variant], // here is the important part
    { 'opacity-50 cursor-not-allowed shadow-none': disabled },
  ]"
>
  Nice flexible button
</button>
```

Otherwise, packages like [tailwind-merge](https://github.com/dcastil/tailwind-merge) also exist to solve this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

After some works with tailwind and some experiences with styled-components / styled-systems on ReactJS, you can actually force some classes with a custom breakpoint because breakpoints have more priority.

I added this to my tailwind config; we can keep the same system mobile first oriented and add some more priority to properties:

```
theme: {
  screens: {
    _: '0px',
  },
},
```

You can use this to define some higher priority properties:

```
_:text-blue // like lg:text-blue
```