# Tailwind + Nuxt 3 SSR dynamic class to child component not working

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

I'm facing an extrange behavior trying to implement dynamic class by props on child element when using Nuxt 3 SSR + Tailwind.

My parent component includes a child component

```html
<section-latest-news :count="12" :columns="4" />
```

My child component tries to render columns based on `columns` property

```html
<template>
  <p class="text-xl text-center uppercase font-semibold border-b-2 mb-4 pb-1 tracking-widest">Últimas noticias {{gridCols}}</p>

  <div :class="`grid gap-5 md:grid-cols-${columns}`" >
    <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id" class="md:mb-0">
      <post-card-image :post="post" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import camelcaseKeys from 'camelcase-keys'

  const props = defineProps({
    excludeSlug:  {
      type: String,
      required: false
    },
    count:  {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
      default: 6
    },
    columns:  {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
      default: 3
    }
  })

  const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig()
  const route = useRoute()

  const { data: posts } = await useFetch(`/public/latest`, {
    params: {
      count: props.count,
      exclude_slug: props.excludeSlug
    },
    key: route.fullPath,
    baseURL: runtimeConfig.public.apiBase,
    transform: (response) => {
      return camelcaseKeys(response, {deep: true})
    }
  })
</script>
```

For some reason, despite I correctly see the class `md:grid-cols-3` in dev tools elements inspector, the class is not applied.
Please note that if I manually set the class without using backticks, the class works as expected, so it's not about CSS layout.

I'm guessing that is something related to SSR and lifecycle, but not sure how to fix it.

EDIT:
The solution as per @kissu recommendation is to use a computed property

```html
const columnsCount = computed(() => {
    return props.columns === 3 ? 'md:grid-cols-3' : 'md:grid-cols-4'
})
```

Then in template simply use it

```
<div class="grid gap-5" :class="columnsCount">
    <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id" class="md:mb-0">
      <post-card-image :post="post" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Luciano, I'm having the same issue. Did you manage to figure it out? Thanks!

Comment: @TimothyHawkins you're not happy with the available answer?

Comment: @TimothyHawkins Please look at my post edit. I've posted the solution using the approach from accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you cannot use dynamic classes with Tailwind: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names
Nothing related to Nuxt, interpolating a utility class is just not feasible since all the classes need to be known ahead of time (during the build): getting written in their full name in the code.

[Here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67382023/8816585) you can still achieve a similar result, but with more work of course.