# Vue.js Change text color based on 3 conditions

Tags: laravel, vue.js, tailwind-css

I have a table with 3 possible values: Firenze, Roma and Milano.
These 3 values need to be associated to 3 different colours.

On page load, every value should render with its associated colour.

Inline conditional rendering can't be used as it only can hold 2 values.

I've tried using functions such as this one below
($missing_item is a v-for single prop got from $missing_items which is an external array prop)

```
function getColour($missing_item){
    switch($missing_item.Deposito){
        case $missing_item.Deposito == 'Firenze':
            return 'text-violet-400';
        case $missing_item.Deposito == 'Roma':
            return 'text-orange-400';
        case $missing_item.Deposito == 'Milano':
            return 'text-green-400';
    }
}
```

I'm calling the function like this: `:class="changeColour()"`

but I keep getting the same error:

> "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError:  Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'Deposito')"

.

My main issue at this point is how to access the renderd "$missing_item.Deposito" inside a function

Comment: Not sure you can access `Deposito` in a switch like you're doing here. Also, how are you calling it? If you have something async, please `await` it.

Comment: Add the html that using changeColour I think you miss passing the parameter to it.
P.S. the function name is weird, you are not changing the color but getting a color, I would call it getColour or something like this

Comment: I'm calling it with a v-class: `:class="changeColour()"`. I think my main issue is understanding how can I access `Deposito` inside a function.

Comment: Does that one help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67382023/8816585

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT:

As I understand you try to call your method from a `v-for`. In this case just add the parameter from the loop:

```html
<div v-for="(missing_item,index) in missing_items" :key="`Item${index}`">
<div :class="changeColour(missing_item)">
I change color depending on which city I am.
</div>
</div>
```

---

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

There is no need for an additional function, Vue can handle this inside the class binding ([see docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes)).

In your example it could look like this:

```html
<div :class="$missing_item.Deposito == 'Firenze' || $missing_item.Deposito == 'Milano' ? 'text-green-400' : 'text-orange-400'">
{{ $missing_item.Deposito }}
</div>
```

While this works, the "Vue way" would be to use it in combination with a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#computed-properties) like this:

```html
<div :class="depositoStyle">
{{ $missing_item.Deposito }}
</div>
```

```js
computed: {
    depositoStyle() {
      return this.$missing_item.Deposito == 'Firenze' || this.$missing_item.Deposito == 'Milano' ? 'text-green-400' : 'text-orange-400';
    }
}
```

If you'd rather use a switch case than the short form, you can insert your switch case function into the computed property and return the end result.

Comment: I've tried inline conditional rendering but unfortunately I haven't found a way to make those work with 3 conditions

Comment: Just chain them like

$missing_item.Deposito == 'Firenze' ? 'text-blue-400' : $missing_item.Deposito == 'Milano' ? 'text-green-400' : $missing_item.Deposito == 'Roma' ? 'text-orange-400' : 'text-red-400'

Comment: If you don't wrap your conditions with parenthesis, they will evaluate to `true || ...` and will return `true`.

Comment: Also, you're assuming that OP will only have those 2 colors. A `switch` is totally viable and fine, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67382023/8816585).

Comment: @kissu I disagree on the parentheses comment. Can spot no difference in the output, here's a [minimal working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQMJwDZwE4AUEMUAngFyIDKUeMYyAlJTXQwFADe7iviECAM5R+OfAEZyreskQBefiVLyFAcgBiMPKjAAvVKsQAfI4rIrEqgLIxsAQzBxDAfktRUADygBaZNp3eACwADMGGlKruXt74DmhBoaoA3Dx8AmDCorh4AExStDLyiERKFhpaOvqGJmbKcmo29o6qjIiukZ4+fqgBIWGIEVE+sQyoCWEpfIjaUCB4SAAGACScAtniAL5FK2v4ORsLKRvs7OmCOKgAdLjIBKoASnAAtnbkqgA0KOhY2XePLy1GCkzhdrnBbuVtHpUG9PmhMGJCJDKgZGEDTkJQTc7o0HHBYV8Eb9rLY8YCkkA)

Comment: @kissu as OP wrote "[...] 3 possible values[...]" => `switch` is a lot more code for this scenario. I agree on more possible values `switch` would be a viable option, you are correct. In this case however I feel chained if is the more concise choice to keep file sizes and buffer usage small. `||` was only used because values were identical. Of course this can be changed into a chained `if` as mentioned in comment above.